# how to integrate Java security layer (Apache Shiro|Spring Security) to webapp menu system

Tags: java, spring-mvc, menu, spring-security, shiro

As the title says, i have a need to create a dynamic `menu stored` as a tree in the `database` and there are plans to put an interface on it.Now i need to decide how to implement the `Access Control Layer` based on what is on the market suitable for this requirement.

I heavily use `Spring IoC`, `spring mvc` etc....with `hibernate` for my project. I've used `apache shiro` before and it's not bad.just that the community is still young so it takes time for a question regarding shiro to have contributions and there is not extensive documentation.

I was still planing on using `shiro` anyway because i've an experience which i don't have with `spring security`.Now the first question should have been **Is is a good idea to tie ACL to menu system|navigation system** .I would be please if anyone could share his experience regarding that.

So on top of my head i have this model in mind `users`, `roles`, `rights`, `users_rights` ,`roles_users`, `roles_rights`

```
users //contains creds and user detail
roles //contains roles
rights // contains rights (including menu entries matching rights, if i have to tie them)
roles_users //many-to-many roles-users with extra columns mapped as entity
roles_rights // many-to-many roles-rights with extra columns mapped as entity

users_rights //many-to-many users-rights mapped as entity with extra columns. special rights for user and overwrite the overall rights given by roles. can deny rights given by a role or add rights not inside any roles
```

so in the rights table i could have like:

```
  id
  name // in the form of admin:users:list
  description
  menu_name // unique name what shows on page
  menu_url
```

the only question is that how do i handle submenu? self many-to-many rights-rights?
at the end it all becomes so complex.So i would like have other perspective, insights ,suggestions. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood what you want.
I think that using a self foreign key is valid. 
However, I would suggest that you compute the "ACL value" of a sub menu upon its creation, or upon update of one of the parents, 
So you won't spent time calculating it while during ACL check for the sub menu. 
I'm sorry if I didn't use the terms correctly, 
What in general I mean is that if you have some value at a tree, and this value might be dependent on the value of the parent node in the tree, 
you should consider to calculate the value for the child node/leaf during insertion , update, or any change at one of the ancestors.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. so nothing is wrong with the structure and how i conceptualize the acl+menu?

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is fine